# SDL: What does "working natively in C++" mean?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, pygame, sdl

I am trying to get a general sense of the phrase above. I was learning PyGame and ran into SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) reference.

Reference to SDL from PyGame: "Pygame is a python wrapper for SDL, written by Pete Shinners." http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html

I looked up SDL (SDL link in the URL above[just click SDL]) and ran into "SDL is written in C, works natively with C++,..." here: http://libsdl.org/

I have considered the word 'native' to imply the original environment but I can't see why something that was written in C is not native in C but rather native in C++?

Does the phrase mean that it works just as well in C++?

Answer (score 7):

> SDL is written in C, works natively with C++, and there are bindings available for several other languages, including C# and Python.

I think you can take away the following from this statement:

- SDL is written in C. Therefore, you can call it directly from your C program.
- C++ "was designed to be source-and-link compatible with C compilers" <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)</sup> so it is only natural that you can use SDL "natively" on your C++ programs, meaning no translation / marshalling layer is needed. You can simply `#include` the header files, and call the APIs directly.
- Other languages, such as C# and Python can't natively call into C APIs, and require mashalling of parameters. This marshalling is done in a [language binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding).

Answer (score 3):

Despite many similarities between the languages, C and C++ are not the same language, and there are a few areas where C code will not compile when used in a C++ compiler.

One such example looks like this:

```
int main()
{
   void *vptr;
   int *iptr = vptr;
   return 0;
}
```

In C, this code will compile. In C++, this is illegal code, and must be rewritten as

```
int main()
{
   void *vptr;
   int *iptr = (int*)vptr;
   return 0;
}
```

That example, and many others, can be found here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-c-program-wont-compiler-c/

When your Python SDL's SDK (... oy.) indicates that it is written in C and works natively in C++, it's almost certainly indicating that no such examples like what I've cited are present in the code.

Answer (score 3):

C++ and C enjoy a particularly good link-time relationship as far as programming languages go. Functions written in either language can be called from code in the other language (as long as all the code is compiled with a consistent toolchain), and the two language share a set of common, fundamental types which "mean the same".

For illustration, consider a simple library function `foo` taking an integer and returning an integer. First, we can write a header file that is valid in both languages:

**lib.h:**

```
#ifndef H_FOO
#define H_FOO

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int foo(int);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif

#endif  // H_FOO
```

Next, we can provide C code that implements this function:

**lib_impl.c:**

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo(int a) { /* ... */ };
```

Finally, we can consume this library from C++:

**app.cpp:**

```
#include "foo.h"

struct XYZ {
  XYZ(int n) : data_(foo(n)) {}
private:
  int data_;
};

int main() { XYZ(10); }
```

At link time, the external symbol `foo` in the `app.cpp` translation unit can be matched with the exported symbol `foo` from the `lib_impl.c` translation unit, even though they are compiled from different languages. The types `int` mean "the same" in both languages in the sense that calling the function with value `10` in C++ causes the correct invocation as if C code had called the function with argument `10` -- the type `int` is represented the same way, and the calling conventions are the same, in both languages.

This fundamental aspect of C and C++, which is not part of any formal standard but effectively universally true, is one of the core compatibility features that allows new C++ programs to build on a wealth of existing code, as well as interact "natively" with many operating system APIs (which are usually provided as C APIs).

Similar link-time interoperability is provided by many tool chains with object code written in assembly (where you need to pay closer attention to the relevant calling conventions), and it is also common with Fortran (though you need to match C and C++ fundamental types with Fortran's types). Other, more recent, languages may also provide "direct" inter-linkability with C (and thus, in a roundabout way, with C++ and Fortran), or otherwise they may require a more library-heavy "foreign function interface" that is a bit more verbose about how it nominates functions provided by a foreign language (e.g. like Java and Go).